# Change color of circularProgressDrawable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, animationdrawable

I have the following code and I want to change the default color of circularProgressDrawable, in Kotlin.

```
val circularProgressDrawable = CircularProgressDrawable(this).apply {
        strokeWidth = 10f
        centerRadius = 50f

    }
```

Comment: [`setColorSchemeColors()` I guess](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/swiperefreshlayout/widget/CircularProgressDrawable#setcolorschemecolors)

Comment: I put the next color and it doesn't work. setColorSchemeColors(0x008000)

Comment: I solved it in the following way: setColorSchemeColors(Color.BLUE) thank you very much

Comment: If you want to use int colors; you can append it with `toInt()`.. like `0xFFFF0000.toInt()`

Comment: Use your resourse color id using this function, such as red color here: `setColorSchemeColors(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red))`